# Blackberry service thread hangs the ui when executing

Tags: blackberry, service, freeze

In my blackberry app i am using alternate entry point and run a thread on startup which does http operation and the same thread is called repeatedly after some time lets say 3 minutes. It does its operation but the problem is it hangs the ui
here is my code.

```
final class sendUnsentService extends Thread {

Timer timer;
TimerTask repeatMe;

sendUnsentService me;

boolean working = false;

public boolean isWorking() {
    return working;
}

public void interrupt() {
    super.interrupt();

    System.out.println("___________________________[STOPSERVICE()]");
    try {
        timer.cancel();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out
        .println("_______________________[PROBLEM STOPPING SERVICE]");
    }
}

public void run() {
    super.run();
    System.out.println("___________________________[STARTSERVICE()]");
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            timer.schedule(repeatMe, 0, 300000);
        };
    }.start();
}

public sendUnsentService() {
    me = this;
    ImageUtils.initPersistentStorage();
    timer = new Timer();

    repeatMe = new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            working = true;
            if (sendUnsentActivity()) {
                me.interrupt();
            }
            working = false;
        }
    };
}
```

I am invoking this thread on some user interaction using this code and then it hangs the ui

```
try {
    helloBerry.service = new sendUnsentService();
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("_____________1 " + e);
}
try {
    helloBerry.service.startService();
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("_____________2 " + e);
}
```

and this is how i call the service to start on device booting in main method using alternate entry point

```
if (args != null && args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("normal")) {
            System.out.println("_________[STARTING APP]");
___________some code here to show a screen
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("_________[STARTING SERVICE]");
            service = new sendUnsentService();
            service.run();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG! Finally i found the thing and its kind of stupid the problem was some sysout statements which i was using to print the data which i was sending to server thank you jprofit for taking interest

i have got another question related to this if you can answer i am starting this thread on some event so when user closes the application it also close this thread i have tried extending application instead of thread but i an not able to handle it remotely.

Comment: You may have to use the RuntimeStore to pass the information to your background app to process, or store it in some standard location and when it sees the existence of some data it knows to begin sending. As far as I'm aware, if the user exits the app there's nothing you can do to prevent the thread from being killed. You could alternatively override the onClose() method of your main screen to background itself if a transfer is still in progress and then close itself when it's complete.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I notice is that you're starting a TimerTask from another Thread. A Timer contains its own Thread, so this is unnecessary -- just call it directly. Also, I don't think you need to make this extend a Thread. What you might want to do is use the TimerTask to reschedule itself if it doesn't error, otherwise just let it stop.

As far as locking up the UI, unless you're doing some odd synchronizing on a RuntimeStore, this shouldn't affect your main program. It should be running as two separate processes, unaware of each other. What circumstances does it freeze under?

Comment: agreed on scheduling timer thing i added that just for a try. the requirement of this app is a background service which will start on device startup and send some data to server on http in my code it is called as sendUnsentActivity() and it will return true if it succeed so we will stop the service. and i also require to start it again on particular event by user and that time it freezes the ui and stays like that untill it finishes its work. anyways thanks for response

Comment: Are you calling `sendUnsentActivity()` directly when doing the on demand call, or wrapping it in its own Thread?

Comment: see i'have just added that block in question